Unable to locate package pcp-system-tools
I try to follow this tutorial and install pcp-system-tools but get an error
Unable to locate package pcp-system-tools


That guide it for Red Hat, not Ubuntu. Are you using Ubuntu at all?

Yes, I am using ubuntu 22.04

You really shouldn't expect instructions meant for Red Hat to work in Ubuntu. A package pcp-system-tools does not exist in Ubuntu repositories.

See at: https://pcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/QG/QuickReferenceGuide.html
